# Using Beyond Compare for Visual Diff in TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, beyondcompare3

I am trying to use Beyond Compare for Visual Diff in TortoiseHg. eg Right click on a modified file in explorer and select Visual Diff from TortoiseHg context menu...

BeyondCompare opens but only shows the 'welcome' screen and not the file I want to diff. Am I missing something?

I have setup the mercurial.ini file as follows:

```
  [extensions]
  extdiff =

  [extdiff]
  cmd.bcomp = C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe
  opts.bcomp = /ro

  [tortoisehg]
  vdiff = bcomp

  [merge-tools]
  bcomp.executable = C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BComp
  bcomp.args = $local $other $base $output
  bcomp.priority = 1
  bcomp.premerge = True
  bcomp.gui = True

  [ui]
  merge = bcomp
```

Comment: Does it work from the command line? In the repository, `hg bcomp` or `hg bcomp -r rev1 -r rev2 file`.  Also, BC3 comes in two flavors: Standard (which doesn't have merging) and Pro (which does).  If you're using Standard, try removing the [merge-tools] and [ui] sections.

Comment: @nc97217 Yes, it works from the command line. Also I am using the Pro version

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found the answer.

*Visual Diff Tool* in *TortoiseHg Global Settings* had to be set to '***beyondcompare3***' instead of '*bcomp*'.

[image: TortoiseHg and Beyond Compare]

Comment: Do you know if the 3-way merge tool has to be set to beyondcompare3 too?

Comment: by the way, how did you found that out?

Comment: @jpbochi - I have 3-way merge set to bcomp and it seems to work fine. I think it was just trial and error although I might have read something somewhere that gave me a pointer.

Comment: Does anyone know the setting to make this work with BC version 2? "BeyondCompare2" didn't work.

Comment: @JohnFx - in `MergeTools.rc` (see my answer) there's also a section for Beyond Compare 2. Might be it can help you.

Answer (score 3):

In our case the same problem happened when we added `mercurial.ini` to `TortoiseHG`. It looks like by default configuration comes from `TortoiseHG\hgrc.d` folder. Specifically diff and merge tools configuration can be found in `MergeTools.rc`.

Just for the reference, here is how `Beyond Compare 3` can be configured manually in `mercurial.ini`:

```
[merge-tools]
bcomp.executable = C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe
bcomp.priority = 1
bcomp.premerge = True
bcomp.gui = True

bcomp.args=$local $other $base /mergeoutput=$output /ro /lefttitle=parent1 /centertitle=base /righttitle=parent2 /outputtitle=merged /automerge /reviewconflicts /solo
bcomp.diffargs=/lro /lefttitle='$plabel1' /righttitle='$clabel' /solo /expandall $parent $child
bcomp.diff3args=$parent1 $parent2 $child /lefttitle='$plabel1' /centertitle='$clabel' /righttitle='$plabel2' /solo /ro
bcomp.dirdiff=True
```

Notice that there's no need in enabling `extdiff` extension. Also TortoiseHG should be restarted to apply this setting.